# function that returns table struct with values when rowIndex is given

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a function/storedProcedure that whenever you call it with params tableName and index.
It will return a string like this:

```
id=2, detail=car repair, concluded=1, bill=No, applicant=others, fk_boxId=1
```

The easiest way was:

```
  select Concat('id=', id, ', detail=', detail, ', concluded=', concluded, ', bill=', bill, ', applicant=', applicant, ', fk_boxId=' ,fk_boxId)
  FROM [CashBox].[dbo].[Concepts]
  where id = 2
```

But I want to be able to send any table and do not have to modify the function everytime a column is added.

I don't know if there is already a function or lib that already do this. I search for it without luck.

With that said. I started to code the function myself. But I'm a bit stuck. This is the idea...

*function:*

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[getColumnValue](@tableName varchar(255), @column varchar(255), @rowIndex int)
    RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ret VARCHAR(255)   
    DECLARE @primaryKey NVARCHAR(255) = (SELECT TOP 1 COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName)
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000) = N'SELECT @column FROM @tableName WHERE @primaryKey=@rowIndex'

    DECLARE @PARAMS NVARCHAR(500);  
    SET @PARAMS = N'@column varchar(255), @tableName varchar(255), @primaryKey varchar(255), @rowIndex int, @ret varchar(255) OUTPUT';  

    exec sp_executesql @SQL, @PARAMS, @column, @primaryKey, @rowIndex, @tableName, @ret output;
    RETURN @ret
END
```

*call:*

```
--PARAMS FOR TESTING
DECLARE @rowIndex varchar(500) = '1'
DECLARE @tableName varchar(500) = 'Concepts'
DECLARE @result varchar(500) = ''

SELECT @result = @result + COLUMN_NAME + '=' + dbo.getColumnValue(@tableName, COLUMN_NAME, @rowIndex) + ', '
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName

SELECT  @result
```

*error message: (this happens inside the function)*

> ```
> Must declare the table variable "@tableName".
> ```

Even if I try to run the function with hardcoded variables the result is blank, I'm affraid that I'm not calling the sp_executesql func right or the query have logic issues that I cannot see. And I'm not getting what I'm trying to do.

In advance thank you. This is the first time I make a question I tried to made it clear as possible.

Comment: This is a good example of the "stored procedure/function for super-generic access" anti-pattern. Unless you are dealing with a *very* dumb client that can literally only process results this way (which is improbable, if it can call a stored procedure) the better solution is to have the client execute a proper `SELECT` for the information it needs and then process the rows in whatever ways it sees fit (possibly by formatting them to a string). This is not a job that should be left to T-SQL code, especially not if you have to throw dynamic code into the mix.

Comment: @JeroenMostert thank you for your comment; the goal of this is not to process data but to log the state of a register before and after update (userActions). I'm not super familiar with good practices, still learning. I appreaciate the feedback.

Comment: For auditing purposes there are other solutions on the DB level -- Change Data Capture, system-managed history tables, extended event traces and hand-written `INSERT`/`UPDATE` triggers, to name a few. If your application has a clearly separated data access layer, wrapping its functions/methods to log the before and after states (possibly with extra data access) is another option. (And if it doesn't, giving it one is a good idea.) Solutions that involve crafting dynamic SQL are among the least attractive, due to the difficulty of writing, troubleshooting and securing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered XML or JSON for your row collection?

**Example**

```
select RowDetailsXML  = (Select A.* for XML RAW)
      ,RowDetailsJSON = (Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper )
  FROM [CashBox].[dbo].[Concepts] A
  where id = 2
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Joe always happy to help